# yo is not running

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yo

I'm getting an error when trying to run yeoman. Just a simple version request. I just installed Node.js using the mac installer v6.2.0 and ran the following:

```
npm install -g yo
```

After getting no errors on install I ran `yo -version`:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:18  
var tabtab = new (require('tabtab').Commands.default)({  
             ^

TypeError: require(...).Commands.default is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:18:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
at node.js:449:3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also found the same problem with latest version of yo. Here is what I did to get me going.

1. Uninstall latest version of yo `npm uninstall -g yo`
2. Install version 1.4.6 with this command `npm i -g yo@1.4.6`

This should get you going.

Comment: This got me rolling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has now been fixed. See the issue on Github [here](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/441#issuecomment-220791460).